React native build project boilerplate fail
image last week the normal React Native project ran smoothly , but yesterday I switched to the boilerplate template and then I cannot run the normal one or the template one anymore , I tried to reinstall Android studio and SDK , I check the environment variable multiple times and has been stucking here for 2 days.
Any help is appreciated , thank you guys
